# How to redirect a URL in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a site setup in SharePoint online at:

> aaa.sharepoint.com/fr

The trouble is  that this is an internal acronym and new staff always go to the long version of this URL.

Is there a way I can redirect

> aaa.sharepoint.com/fundraising

to

> aaa.sharepoint.com/fr

without having to create another SharePoint site and a redirection page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have much options: being in SP Online you don't own the infrastructure, thus you can't rely on some techniques which may be overkill for this simple case, such as plugging in a custom *HttpModule* in the IIS pipeline, or working with IIS Rewrite URLs.
The only would be putting an extra 'entrance door' for your SP Online, by using for instance a custom domain (e.g. portal.contoso.com).
Your users will use the custom domain URL instead to access (no more tenant.sharepoint.com); and associated with that you can have some infrastructure you control, such as a reverse proxy. You'd put your rewrite rules there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some JavaScript code within your `/fundraising` page. You can use a Script Editor webpart to insert this code:

`window.location="https://aaa.sharepoint.com/fr"`

Comment: Yup, well aware of that and mentioned at the end of my question. I'm looking for something a bit cleaner.